# Arabic from Android through PHP into mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, utf-8, arabic

I have an android app that calls a restful API in PHP that saves information in mysql. The URL contains Arabic characters in one of its parameters.

When I send this URL from the browser itself, I eventually see the Arabic characters in the DB (and when echoing) but when I call this URL from the app, it echos back (I added echo command on the php side) and store in the DB "?????".

When calling the API, I do the following:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();       
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Think so. And we are missing something because you did not show the url nor how you handle it.

Comment: actually I don't handle it. When I had English chars I just needed to convert the spaces into %20 so all I do is urlString = urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

Comment: Try to url encode it.